# Reduce a facet plot to one ggplot

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

Please see below the dataset that I am working with:

```
  index d1_t1 d1_t2 d1_t3 d1_t4 d2_t1 d2_t2 d2_t3 d2_t4 d3_t1 d3_t2 d3_t3 d3_t4 d4_t1 d4_t2 d4_t3 d4_t4 d5_t1 d5_t2 d5_t3 d5_t4 d6_t1 d6_t2 d6_t3 d6_t4 d7_t1 d7_t2 d7_t3 d7_t4
1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     0     1     0     1     1     0     1     0     1     0     1     1     1     1     1     1
2     2     1     1     0     1     0     1     0     0     0     1     0     1     0     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0
3     3     1     1     1     0     1     1     0     1     1     0     1     0     1     0     1     1     0     1     1     1     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
4     4     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
```

A short explanation of the variables:

```
d1t1=Day 1 time 1
d1t2=Day 1 time 2
....
d2t1=Day2 time 1
d2t2=Day2 time 2
0,1= different types of measurements taken at a specific time
```

I would like to create a line graph using ggplot to show the number of measurements per minute during a week. So basically x-axis to have time, y-axis to have the highest number of measures taken during the week. And the lines show the number of measures taken by the day.

Sample data:

```
df<-structure(list(index=c (101,200,200,101), d1_t1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1),
               d1_t2 = c(1, 1, 1, 1), 
               d1_t3 = c(1, 1, 1, 1), 
               d1_t4 = c(1, 1, 0,  1),
               d2_t1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1), 
               d2_t2 = c(1, 1, 1, 1), 
               d2_t3 = c(1, 0, 1 ,1), 
               d2_t4 =c(1,0,1,1),
               d3_t1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1),
               d3_t2 = c(1, 1, 1, 1), 
               d3_t3 = c(1, 1, 1, 1), 
               d3_t4 = c(1, 0, 1,  1),
               d4_t1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1), 
               d4_t2 = c(1, 1, 1, 1), 
               d4_t3 = c(1, 1, 1 ,1), 
               d4_t4 =c(1,1,1,1),
               d5_t1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1),
               d5_t2 = c(1, 1, 1, 1), 
               d5_t3 = c(1, 1, 1, 1), 
               d5_t4 = c(1, 1, 1,  1),
               d6_t1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1), 
               d6_t2 = c(1, 1, 1, 1), 
               d6_t3 = c(1, 0, 1 ,1), 
               d6_t4 =c(1,0,1,1),
               d7_t1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1), 
               d7_t2 = c(1, 1, 1, 1), 
               d7_t3 = c(1, 0, 1 ,1), 
               d7_t4 =c(1,0,1,1)), row.names = c(NA,4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Basically I would like to reduce the above plot to a geom_line graph with days showing the patterns.

[image]

Basically I would like to have lines colored by day.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, you are looking for :

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -index, 
               names_to = c('day', 'time'), 
               names_sep = "_") %>%
  group_by(day,time) %>% 
  summarise(value=sum(value)) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(time, value, fill = day) + 
  geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

[image]